# Generic static class method

Tags: typescript

How can you type a method which uses a static property on extended classes?

Given the javascript:

```js
class Animal {}
Animal.makeNoise = (language) => this.sounds[language];

class Dog extends Animal {}
Dog.sounds = {
  english: 'woof-woof',
  portuguese: 'au-au'
}
```

I thought this might work

```
abstract class Animal {
  static sounds: { [key in string]: false | string[] | string }
  static makeNoise
    = <S extends typeof Dog.sounds, L extends keyof S>(language: L): S[L]
      => this.sounds[language];
}
class Dog extends Animal {
  static sounds: {
    english: 'woof-woof',
    portuguese: 'au-au'
  }
}
Dog.makeNoise('english') // => "woof-woof"
```

But I cant find a way to reference the `this.sounds` of every extended class. Is there any right way to do this yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the static method to work for any derived classes you can use the `this` parameter to capture the actual type of `sound` in the derived class. You can then use this type information to extract the actual sound type:

```
abstract class Animal {
    static sounds: Record<string, false | string[] | string>
    static makeNoise<TSounds extends typeof Animal['sounds'], L extends keyof TSounds>(this: { sounds: TSounds }, language: L): TSounds[L] {
        return this.sounds[language];
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    static sounds: {
        english: 'woof-woof',
        portuguese: 'au-au'
    }
}
Dog.makeNoise('english') // => "woof-woof"
```

Comment: Perhaps the return type of `makeNoise` should be `TSounds[L]`?

Comment: @jcalz yes, the `TThis` was left from a previous version and I didn't notice the red squiggly and inference produced the correct return for `makeNoise`. 10x :)